# After Pasting a Feature in Pro, Why Does Move Automatically Activate?

Tags: arcgis-pro, editing, move, modify-features

Since moving to ArcGIS Pro 2.5 (and still existing in 2.6) when I am editing a feature and I copy and paste it, once pasting, the modify features move command is activated. This can lead to issues of accidentally moving the feature and creates a few extra steps when I am copying and pasting multiple features.

**Is there anyone to deactivate this functionality, did I accidentally enable it?**

My process for copying and pasting (copying a parcel to a development dataset) is as follows:

1. Select the parcel
2. Copy using the copy function in the edit toolbar of the ribbon
3. Paste using the paste function in the edit toolbar of the ribbon

Once I hit paste, the modify features panel comes up and move is activated on the pasted parcel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I verified that this (undesirable) behavior still occurs in 2.6.1 patched latest as of this answer.

*(Caveat: you're probably not gonna like my suggested solution.)*

First: this sure looks like an ESRI bug, IMHO, because if you simply create a feature, or simply select an existing feature, then the Edit > Move tool is not automatically activated.

**Post it to GeoNet** with tags: ArcGIS Pro, Editor, Copy/Paste and such.

Here's what I suggest you can do to solve your own problem (after posting the bug evidence to GeoNet):  Create your own Paste command using the [ArcGIS Pro SDK for Microsoft .NET](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/sdk/)

Obviously you would want your custom paste command to only be 'active' if there is something in the clipboard; you also want it to respond to ctrl-V.

- Then it would perform a 'normal' `Paste`
- followed by creating an in-memory list of the ObjectID(s) the Paste just created
- followed by a `Finish Sketch` (the `F2`)
- followed by a `Select by Attributes` using that in-memory Oid list

The net result should look just like you pasted the feature(s) and they stayed selected and nothing else (unreliable/unpredicted) happened within the GUI.

Sorry it's happened to you; perhaps not the bounty-worthy answer you were looking for.

Comment: PS -- with your skills, you might be able to clear selection in Python with some kind of editor event listener?

Comment: Thank you @JasonInVegas, I've been able to build a work around here with your suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

I talked to the Editing team and this behavior is by design - they'll consider adding an option to change/disable it.

In the meantime they suggested a workaround: if you hit Esc after the paste is completed, it will de-activate the tool.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Jeremy, I appreciate the information and you forwarding this on. I wanted to give you the bounty, but Jason gave me work around that has worked around.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy for 'hearing' us. -- although I gotta figure you have more than 181 worth of GIS points!